# Why does training succeed and predict fail with keras and tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I train a CNN to detect the presence of hazard ids ([example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/ADR33_UN1203.svg/220px-ADR33_UN1203.svg.png)) on images.

I get a 99% accuracy in training. Then I try to predict on pictures from the training set and it fails to give the correct estimation.

Can you please tell me how this is possible?

Code taken from Google's cats and dogs example (https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/practica/image-classification/exercise-1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

def predict(frame):
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (150, 150))
    frame = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
    frame = np.asarray(frame, dtype='int32')
    frame = frame / 255
    return model.predict(frame)

base_dir = './cats_and_dogs_filtered'
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'validation')

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
train_dogs_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'dogs')

validation_cats_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'cats')
validation_dogs_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'dogs')

train_cat_fnames = os.listdir(train_cats_dir)
print(train_cat_fnames[:10])

train_dog_fnames = os.listdir(train_dogs_dir)
train_dog_fnames.sort()
print(train_dog_fnames[:10])

img_input = layers.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(img_input)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(img_input, output)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),
              metrics=['acc'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,  # This is the source directory for training images
        target_size=(150, 150),  # All images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=20,
        # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=100,  # 2000 images = batch_size * steps
      epochs=15,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=50,  # 1000 images = batch_size * steps
      verbose=2)

#model.save("trained_cnn_cats_and_dogs.h5")

for i in range(100):
    frame_cat = cv2.imread(train_cats_dir + "/" + train_cat_fnames[i])
    predictions_cat = predict(frame_cat)

    frame_dog = cv2.imread(train_dogs_dir + "/" + train_dog_fnames[i])
    predictions_dog = predict(frame_dog)

    print("Dog: " + str(predictions_dog[0]) + " Cat: " + str(predictions_cat[0]))
```

For the dataset I have copied the dogs over the cats (so that both image sets are the same) and then put a hazard id over each former cat picture: [link to the data (dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zpnysl80l48l5a2/AACDlOctpzJe4c8nnEAUuzfla?dl=0)

So I have "dogs without a hazard id" in the dogs directory and "dogs with hazard id sign" in the cats directory.

Output:

```
Epoch 15/15
 - 14s - loss: 0.0398 - acc: 0.9910 - val_loss: 0.1332 - val_acc: 0.9760
Dog: [0.9991505] Cat: [0.9996587]
Dog: [0.9996618] Cat: [0.9988152]
Dog: [0.99470115] Cat: [0.99987006]
```

So I can't tell if there is a hazard sign or not: Dog would mean "no hazard sign", cat would mean "hazard sign".

The same code works perfectly with the original cats and dogs data.

Comment: i provided an answer, but i deleted it, after re-reading the question i understood what you did, so the answer was unrelated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the byte order of cv2.imread() which is Blue-Green-Red whereas ImageDataGenerator uses Red-Green-Blue.

Solution:

```
def prepare_frame(frame):
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # <- correct byte order!!!
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (150, 150))
    frame = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
    frame = np.asarray(frame, dtype='int32')
    frame = frame / 255
    return frame
```

Original cats & dogs dataset: still works (I guess the colors just had no impact there - very interesting!)
Batch Size: tested with 1 and 20, both work

Thanks for all your comments - I really appreciate your help!
I hope somebody else finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand this correctly your labels "cat" and "dog" should actually represent "Harzard sign present" and "Hazard sign not present" correct?

I cannot see you specifying your labels anywhere?

Can you please provide a link to the example you mentioned?

(I would normally post this as a comment, but I do not have sufficient rep.)

EDIT: It seems to me that there is something wrong with your labels.
The first thing I would do is verify that your training data is actually correctly labeled. It seems to simply treat files in different folders as different labels.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I've added the link to the original question: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/practica/image-classification/exercise-1

Comment: The labelling should be taken care of by [ImageDataGenerator] (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#class_imagedatagenerator) : _"... the list of classes will be automatically inferred from the subdirectory names/structure under directory, where each subdirectory will be treated as a different class (and the order of the classes, which will map to the label indices, will be alphanumeric)."_

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct. It might be not a problem of your code, instead a problem of data. Maybe the distribution of the validation set is different from the training set.

To verify, you should replace the who validation set by a portion of the training set and run the code to see if the algorithm is doing well. If the accuracy on this 'fake' validation is low, it's the problem of your code. Otherwise, you should think about a better way to split your data

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I used 300 randomly selected training images per category (cats, dogs) as new validation data. That makes 700 images (per category) for training and 300 for validation. Unfortunately, still the same result: very high accuracy during training, no luck with any predictions on the same (training) dataset.

Comment: In this case, I think there must be something wrong with your code, specifically when evaluating the performance.

Comment: I currently think it has something to do with training batches of 20 images and predicting single images. Makes me wonder why it worked with the original dataset though - I'm investigating.